# How to fix update-initramfs and kernel in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: dpkg

After running for example sudo apt-get upgrade, the following error code is generated:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-109-generic (4.15.0-109.110) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-109-generic
Fatal: open /dev/sda: No medium found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-109-generic (4.15.0-109.110) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-109-generic

evdi:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - This kernel never originally had a module by this name
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-109-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-109-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo:
Fatal: open /dev/sda: No medium found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-109-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-109-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.15.0-109-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Reinstalling intitramfs-tools does not work. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how to fix this?

EDIT:
The problem originates from the lilo.conf file. Herein the following directories are defined:
boot = /dev/sda
root = /dev/sda1

However, this is not the boot device and also not the root partition I think. I have listed all my devices below:

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/93
loop1       7:1    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/100
loop2       7:2    0   2,4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/748
loop3       7:3    0   2,4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/730
loop4       7:4    0   2,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
loop5       7:5    0  54,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop6       7:6    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1754
loop7       7:7    0    97M  1 loop /snap/core/9289
loop8       7:8    0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop9       7:9    0 160,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop10      7:10   0 255,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop11      7:11   0  96,5M  1 loop /snap/core/9436
loop12      7:12   0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop13      7:13   0 161,4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop14      7:14   0   276K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/539
loop15      7:15   0 255,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
loop16      7:16   0   276K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/550
loop17      7:17   0   2,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
nvme0n1   259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   499M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part 
nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 235,5G  0 part 
nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   2,4G  0 part 
nvme1n1   259:5    0 931,5G  0 disk 
nvme1n1p1 259:6    0    16M  0 part 
nvme1n1p2 259:7    0 686,4G  0 part 
nvme1n1p3 259:8    0 245,1G  0 part /
```

If I change the boot to /dev/nvme1n1p3 for example, the following error is displayed:

```
Warning: SATA partition is in the high region (>15)
LILO needs kernel in one of the first 15 SATA partitions. If you need support for kernel in SATA partitions of the higher region than try grub2 for this purpose!
Fatal: Sorry, cannot handle device 0x10308
```

I do not know how to adjust something or how to use grub2, so is there anyone who does know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the context. Did you see this `Fatal: open /dev/sda: No medium found`? It is weird. You probably misconfigured something. What is your filesystem? Are you using partitions? Please post output of `cat /etc/fstab`, `cat /etc/default/grub`, `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: This doesn't look like Ubuntu. What OS/version is it?

Comment: I have edited the question to answer your comments